# Different Gradle dependency for test than for compile

Tags: java, android, testing, gradle, dependencies

I am facing this issue with Android/Gradle dependency system

1. I have quite a complex JAR library with certain API - say other.jar
2. This other.sdk is completely out of my control
3. This other.sdk only works on a real phone
4. I need to write the jUnit tests to be executed on Jenkins (w/o any real phone attached)
5. Therefore I wrote anothe JAR file called say otherMock.jar
6. This otherMock.jar has exactly the same API as other.jar

Now I need to do something like this in my build.gradle file:

```
...

dependencies {
    ...
    testCompile files('libs/otherMock.jar')
    debugCompile files('libs/other.jar')
    releaseCompile files('libs/other.jar')
    ...
}

...
```

Unfortunately, Gradle seems then to be including both the other.jar and the otherMock.jar within my test build.

I do understand that for majority of builds (including all my previous) it is perfectly desirable behavior.

But for my particular case it is an issue.

So I would need (for example) something like this:

```
...
dependencies {
    if(<I failed to realize which condition to write here to learn it is going to be a test>) {
        testCompile ...
    } else {
        debugCompile ...
        releaseCompile ...
    }
}
```

Or better:

```
...
dependencies {
    testCompile ...
    debugCompile ... {
        exclude <when test build - what to write here?>
    }
}
...
```

I did my best to realize how to configure Gradle to do what I need here, but I failed :(

On the other hand, I cannot believe Gradle would not be flexible enough to achieve that. I hope it is too just hard to find out for me :) ...

Please do not advice me with:

- Wrapping other.jar and injecting the mocked variant when running tests (I know that would be possible but it is a lot of extra work which makes no sense to me)
- Attaching the real phone to my Jenkins (I cannot do that as I have no physicall access to Jenkins virtual machine + on a real device I would not be able to control the mock at all)
- Applying other mocking mechanisms like mockito - I also tried this but the other.jar library is not following good design principles therefore it is hard to mock in a standard way - I still did not try powermock but again it makes no sense to me to try if I succeed with the dependencies

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Gradle configurations](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.Configuration.html) and [Gradle test](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test.html) to define custom configuration and exclude it from test task classpath:

```
configurations {
   other.extendsFrom compile //latter is parent for both debugCompile and releaseCompile
}

test {
   classpath -= configurations.other
}


dependencies {
   testCompile files('libs/otherMock.jar')
   other files('libs/other.jar')
}
```

Comment: Does not work with Android gradle plugin to me. The test task is missing.